# Error in integrating com.coboltforge.slidemenu library in my application

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am facing these problems when integrating slide menu library in Android `Studio(1.1.0)` project. I am using `sdk 24.1.2`.
The error is at line 63 in the code given below:

```
super(act, R.id.menu_label, items);
```

However i have integrated this library in one of my eclipse project & no error has been evolved there.

Reports two types of problems:

```
Supplying the wrong type of resource identifier. For example, when calling Resources.getString(int id), you should be passing R.string.something, not R.drawable.something.
Passing the wrong constant to a method which expects one of a specific set of constants. For example, when calling View#setLayoutDirection, the parameter must be android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR or android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL.
```

Comment: seems like you are passing the wrong thing in that constructor, I would guess R.id.menu_label shouldn't be an id but rather a layout or a menu.

Comment: I know that it is demanding layout attribute but i have tried with the same thing in eclipse without any problem.

Comment: If it's asking for a layout you should pass something like R.layout.layout_name. I am not sure why in eclipse was working but Android Studio has more lint options and error checking which might explain it.